# Angular 6 lib : how to export generated protobuf models?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protocol-buffers

I got 3 projects using a `common-lib` (in the same repository, multi-projects). `common-lib` exports common components/services/utils successfully.
But now, I want to also share here my generated protocol buffers ... but files are not included when I build the lib..

I think it's related to the fact that protobufs are JS files and not TS files (but declaration TS files are present)

Any help ?

public_api.ts :

```
export * from './lib/models/errors/ui'; // ok, it's a .ts file
export * from './lib/models/protobuf-generated/public/API_pb'; // ko, it's a .d.ts file and .js file
export * from './lib/models/protobuf-generated/public/API_pb_service'; // ko, it's a .d.ts file and .js file
```

generated protobufs folder :

[image]